# jQuery Address: Certify that user is pressing forward button and not back button

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-history, jquery-address

**EDIT 3**:
This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ffwb/show/) works with the plugin, I almost have it.

**EDIT 2**: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZ3pr/).I can't get the plugin to work there, but maybe it is easier to analyze.

---

In the webpage I am building, Articles(posts) and new Pages are loaded via Ajax. At the same time when new Ajax-content is loaded, the address bar changes (using [jQuery Address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)).

So a normal navigation would go like this:

> /       /page2       /page3       /article7       /page3       /page4

Please note that in this navigation, no browser button was pressed, when exiting the **article7** the website goes back to its prior url which is **page3** in this case.

The plugin doesn't detect when the user pressed the back or forward button. I managed to figure out a way to know when the user presses back or forward button:

Each time new content is added and the address is changed I store the new address in an array. If the user presses the back'or'forward button I analise it this way:

> if (new_url == penultimate_value_in_array) => Back button pressed (errase
>   last value from array)
> else => Forward button pressed (add new value to array)

This works correctly for this kind of navigation:

> /       /page2       /page3       /page4

In my case, it works perfect for the Back button. However if the user presses Forward from /article7 to /page3 the function will read it as Back. Here is an example to understand what I mean:

---

user is in /page4 and presses Back -> new_page=/page3 that is equal to penultimate_page_in_array(/page3) => BACK

> /       /page2       /page3       /article7       /page3       /page4

user is in /page3 and presses Back -> new_page=/article7 that is equal to penultimate_page_in_array(/article7) => BACK

> /       /page2       /page3       /article7       /page3

user is in /article7 and presses Back -> new_page=/page3 that is equal to penultimate_page_in_array(/page3) => BACK

> /       /page2       /page3       /article7

user is in /page3 and presses Back -> new_page=/page2 that is equal to penultimate_page_in_array(/page2) => BACK

> /       /page2       /page3

user is in /page2 and presses Forward -> new_page=/page3 that is NOT equal to penultimate_page_in_array(/) => FORWARD

> /       /page2

user is in /page3 and presses Forward -> new_page=/article7 that is NOT equal to penultimate_page_in_array(/page2) => FORWARD

> /       /page2       /page3

user is in /article7 and presses Forward -> new_page=/page3 that IS equal to penultimate_page_in_array(/page3) => BACK (**and here the value should be FORWARD**)

> /       /page2       /page3       /article7

How can I introduce another statement that would determine that False Back should be Forward?

---

---

**EDIT:**

This is the code I am using, I'm not sure if it will help to resolve the issue but here it is:

```
var site_url = 'www.mysite.com',
    last_visited_url = '',
    just_visited_url = $.address.baseURL().replace(site_url,''),
    visited_pages_array = [just_visited_url],
    page_number = '';
```

when visiting new page:
ajax call,then:

```
last_visited_url = just_visited_url;
page_number = $('a.next_page_link').attr('href').replace(site_url,''); // /page3 for example
$.address.state(site_url).value(page_number);
just_visited_url = page_number;
visited_pages_array.push(just_visited_url);
```

when loading Article:
ajax call,then:

```
article_url = $('a.article_title').attr('href').replace(site_url,''); // /article7 for example
last_visited_url = just_visited_url;
$.address.state(site_url).value(article_url);
just_visited_url = article_url;
visited_pages_array.push(just_visited_url);
```

when existing an Article:

```
last_visited_url = just_visited_url;
$.address.state(site_url).value(page_number); // This page number is the last page_number value
just_visited_url = page_number;
visited_pages_array.push(just_visited_url);
```

And this code is executed when the user presses some of the browser butons:

```
$.address.externalChange(function() {

    var newPage = $.address.baseURL().replace(site_url,'');

    if (visited_pages_array[visited_pages_array.length-2] == newPage) {

        visited_pages_array.splice(visited_pages_array.length-1 , 1);
        console.log('BACK pressed');

    } else if (visited_pages_array.length > 1) {

        visited_pages_array.push(newPage);
        console.log('FORWARD pressed');

    } else {

        console.log('REFRESH pressed');

    }

});
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code?

Comment: Im not sure if I agree with the edit of the question.Im using jQuery Adress plugin but Im asking for the logic behind the statments not exactly about the plugin.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: "The plugin doesn't detect when the user pressed the back or forward button." => is there a difference between going to the `page3` url with the back button, going to the `page3` url with the forward button, and going to the `page3` url by typing it in the browser's address bar ?

Comment: The url is exactly the same in the three cases:  www.myweb.com/?page=3

Answer (score 3):

The fastest and easiest solution I can think of is the following:

Your problem is that when your "next" and "previous" pages are the same, pressing `Forward` is detected by your code as `Back` because the following condition is `true`:

```
visited_pages_array[visited_pages_array.length-2] == newPage
```

I would recommend 2 things in your case:

1. **DO NOT** delete the address you just left from `visited_pages_array` as in:

   `visited_pages_array.splice(visited_pages_array.length-1 , 1);`

   that way `visited_pages_array` will keep a list of all visited pages.
2. Create a new "global" variable called `current_page_index` that will hold the index of  your current page in `visited_pages_array` which can now hold `visited_pages_array.length-1` if you are currently at the last page visited **or lower values** if you used `Back` button.

Now all you have to do is change your condition from:

```
if (visited_pages_array[visited_pages_array.length-2] == newPage)
```

to:

```
if (visited_pages_array[current_page_index-1] == newPage)
```

**Notes:**

1. When you detect a `Back` click - do this: `current_page_index--;` and when you detect a `Forward` do: `current_page_index++;`
2. When the user clicks your navigation to move the another page, **MAKE SURE** to do: `visited_pages_array.splice(current_page_index+1 ,visited_pages_array.length-current_page_index-1);` (removing all the saved `Forward`s) before pushing the new address to the end of `visited_pages_array`. And ofcourse setting `current_page_index++;`

I hope this is clear enough, I couldn't get your jsFiddle to work so explained as clearly as I can. GL :)

**EDIT:** another idea taken from the `jQuery Address` docs: (not sure about this one though)

> $.address.externalChange(fn): Binds a function to be executed when the
>   address is changed from the browser usually when entering the page or
>   using the back and forward buttons. **The function receives a single
>   event object parameter** that contains the following properties: value,
>   path, pathNames, parameterNames, parameters and queryString.

which means your function can receive an event object - try `alert()`ing all it's properties maybe the answer will be lying there

```
$.address.externalChange(function(ev){
    // loop and alert ev's properties
    for (var p in ev) {
        alert(p + ': ' + ev[p]);
    }
})
```

Comment: current_page_index initial value should be 1 or 0?  __current_page_index++;__ should be settled before  __visited_pages_array.splice(current_page_index+1 ,visited_pages_array.length-current_page_index-1);__?

Comment: Ok, I think I settled it correctly however the False Back still shows.Ill try to make a jsFiddle. Thanks.

Comment: `current_page_index` initial value should be 0. `current_page_index++;` should be settled after `visited_pages_array.splice(current_page_index+1 ,visited_pages_array.length-current_page_index-1);` and `visited_array_pages.push(...)`

Comment: yes, I've just tested it myself.. not helpful. However I found a javascript class that can tap to the back button click event - try to add it to your code - http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/ - I've tested it and it's working.

Comment: I made this fiddle trying to emulate my case, and seems to work. I'm so connfused right now: http://jsfiddle.net/fZ3pr/3/

Comment: Please forget about the jquery Adress, I was just trying to emulate it in text printed, where seems to work comparing those two arrays. Thanks for your link but as can be seen in the example (http://www.brookebryan.com/code/backbutton/), if I click back it fires alert. but if I click forward and back again it doesn't fire the alert..

Comment: I just emulated on the printed text, not in the address (I tried to find the correct way of comparing the results)

Comment: Yes!! - this is your way for detecting if the externalChange was done by `Back` or `Forward`

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure about your logic here, but what you are describing sounds like a perfect candidate for html5 pushState (browser history state manipulation) functionality.  Here are a few good summaries:

- [Reference 1](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)
- [Reference 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Also, here are some good demos from fellow stackoverflow users:

[HTML5 History API Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571734/html5-history-api-demo)